# How can I hide the original website content if the internet isn't connected?

Tags: reactjs, internet-explorer-8, blockchain, wagmi

I am using wagmi wallet connector and it give error whenever internet isn't connected and the whole screen went red to get rid of it I decided to put internet check on my app, I have used multiple way but none of them worked for me.

The following is the code of my index.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { EthereumClient, w3mConnectors, w3mProvider } from '@web3modal/ethereum'
import { Web3Modal } from '@web3modal/react'
import { configureChains, createConfig, WagmiConfig } from 'wagmi'

import { InjectedConnector } from '@wagmi/core/connectors/injected'
import { WalletConnectConnector } from '@wagmi/core/connectors/walletConnect'
import { sepolia } from 'wagmi/chains'

const chains = [sepolia]
const projectId = '*****************'

const { publicClient, webSocketPublicClient } = configureChains(chains, [w3mProvider({ projectId })])
const wagmiConfig = createConfig({
  connectors: [
    new InjectedConnector({ chains }),
    new WalletConnectConnector({
      chains,
      options: {
        projectId: projectId,
      },
    }),
  ],
  autoConnect: true,
  connectors: w3mConnectors({ projectId, chains }),
  publicClient, webSocketPublicClient
})
const ethereumClient = new EthereumClient(wagmiConfig, chains)


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Provider store={store}>
      <WagmiConfig config={wagmiConfig}>
        <App ethereumClient={w3mProvider} />
      </WagmiConfig>
      </Provider>
    </BrowserRouter>
    
    <Web3Modal projectId={projectId} ethereumClient={ethereumClient} />
  </React.StrictMode>
);


reportWebVitals();
```

I have use multiple options to get rid of it but all of them got wasted, and the next code is of my App.js file

```
import React, { useState,useEffect } from 'react'
import Head from './Component/Head/Head'
import "./App.css"
import { ToastContainer, toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { loadFull } from "tsparticles";
import 'react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Main_home_page from './Component/Main_home_page/Main_home_page';
import Footer_up from './Component/Footer_up/Footer_up';
import Swap from './Component/Swap/Swap';
import {CrowdFundingProvider} from './Context/Crowdfunding'
import Index from './Index.jsx';

 function App() {

  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(navigator.onLine);


  useEffect(() => {
    const handleOnline = () => {
      setIsOnline(true);
    };

    const handleOffline = () => {
      setIsOnline(false);
    };

    window.addEventListener('online', handleOnline);
    window.addEventListener('offline', handleOffline);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('online', handleOnline);
      window.removeEventListener('offline', handleOffline);
    };
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isOnline) {
      toast.warn("Check your Internet Connection.")
      console.log('Offline: Please check your internet connection');
    }
  }, [isOnline]);

  return (
    <div className='' >
      {isOnline?(
 <div className='back'>
        
 <CrowdFundingProvider>
 
   <ToastContainer />
   <Head />
   <Routes>
     
     <Route path='/' element={<Main_home_page />} />
     <Route path='/Swap' element={<Swap />} />
     <Route path='/Index' element={<Index/>}/>

   </Routes>
   <Footer_up />
  
   </CrowdFundingProvider>
  
 </div>
      ):
      (
        <div>
          <h1>Check Your Connection</h1>
          <p>Please check your internet connection and try again.</p>
        </div>
      )
      }
     
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

I have used react-detect-offline for it also, but It also didn't work when I cover my all app in it them whole screen disappears without showing even single error even on console., here is my code for that,
import React from "react";

```
import {Detector} from "react-detect-offline";

const CheckConnection=props=>{
    return(
        <>
        <Detector
        render={({online})=>(
            online? props.chindren:
            <div style={{paddingTop:'10px', textAlign:'center'}}>
              
                <h1 style={{marginBottom:'5px'}}>No Connection</h1>
                <h4 style={{margin:'0'}}>Please check your internet connection</h4>
            </div>
        )}
        
        />
            
            </>
    )
}
export default CheckConnection;
```

I tried my best to explain the problem. Kindly try to locate what mistake am I making and help me to get rid of it.

Comment: Off topic protip: You shouldn't be skipping heading levels in your document. Doing so suggests that you're using headings for _styling_ rather than content structure, which is bad practice. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Heading_Elements#usage_notes.